# How to downcast this to the base class?

Tags: c#

I have this class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class AClass : SomeFrameworkClass {
  [WorkOnThisProperty(With.Some.Context)]
  private MyObject MyProperty { get; set; }  

  public override void OnSomethingHappened() {
    ExternalFramework.WorkOn(this);
  }
}

public class BClass : AClass {
  // ... Snip ...
}
```

`ExternalFramework` is operating on `this`: an instance of `BClass` but i need it to operate on `this` as an instance of `AClass` because `ExternalFramework` only works on the type of the object passed in and does not go up the inheritance hierarchy. How can i downcast `this` into `AClass` so `ExternalFramework` can actually detect `MyProperty`?

I've tried casting `this` to `object` and then to `AClass`, and casting it directly to `AClass` but as the cast is unnecessary it doesn't seem to run. What can i do about this?

EDIT: `ExternalFramework` is [Cheeseknife](https://github.com/MarcelBraghetto/Cheeseknife). I am trying to inject a couple views into a base fragment class that has all the reusable logic while child fragment classes implement some specific behaviour tuning.

Comment: Make the property public or at least protected. A private property doesn't make much sense. Downcasting doesn't allow you to use a paren'ts *private* fields, properties or methods.

Comment: There is nothing you can do if code just calls `GetType()`... Unless you explain/show how that "external framework" uses type there is not much hope for an answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nailed it. I feel so dumb right now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all private members of a class can only be accessed *inside* of the same class.

With this code:

```
class A { private string Property { get; set; } }
class B : A { public string Proxy => Property; }
```

We'll get compilation error because class `B` cannot access private property from class `A`, but if change keyword to `protected` :

`class A { protected string Property { get; set; } }`

It should work.